# Insert newpage before section but prevent pagebreak after part

Tags: macros, sectioning, page-breaking, parts

Maybe some of you can already guess what I'm trying to achieve; I want to redefine some commands with the following result: every `\section` should start on a new page **except** for sections which are placed directly after a \part.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\part{Part one}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Third section}
\lipsum[1]


\part{Part two}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

In the above example, every `\section` should create a new page but not the "First sections", since they're located directly after a `\part` command.

I started with

```
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\newpage\oldsection}
```

but then I got stuck not finding an answer to the question on how to built up an exception (so that the `\part` sticks together with the following `\section` on one page).

I hope you know how to cope with my problem - you probably do; I never saw you being unable to solve a problem!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Probably not an elegant solution, but you can use `\oldsection` (or  call it `\firstsection`) for the first section in a part.

Comment: I'm so sorry. In fact, I read about this some time ago already; but since I wasn't too sure about this anymore, I thought I'd better be polite rather than not.

Back to topic: I started thinking about a solution with the "samepage" environment, but finally, I think this wouldn't work neither since it would get far too complex to create an abstract environment that way, including variables which define the "next section title" and so on...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a conditional to turn off page breaks after a part:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{afterpart}
\pretocmd{\section}
  {\iftoggle{afterpart}
    {\global\togglefalse{afterpart}}% we're after a part
    {\clearpage}% we're not immediately after a part
  }{}{}
\pretocmd{\part}
  {\clearpage % do a page break
   \global\toggletrue{afterpart}% tell \section we're just after a part
  }
  {}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\part{Part one}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Third section}
\lipsum[1]


\part{Part two}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

If you want to exclude some section from the mechanism, add

```
\newcommand{\sectionnobreak}{%
  \global\toggletrue{afterpart}%
  \section
}
```

to your preamble and use `\sectionnobreak` instead of `\section`. Alternatively, add

```
\newcommand{\NPB}{%
  \global\toggletrue{afterpart}%
}
```

to the preamble and type

```
\NPB\section{Title}
```

for the section you want to exclude from the automatic page break. The first section after `\part` will not need any adjustment in any case.

Comment: worked great for me!
One more tiny variation: would there also be a possibility to exclude one more section manually (in my case it would be the "second section" in "part one")?

Comment: @user43961 Yes, of course. Expect a fix soon.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than use a conditional I prefer a command that is defined to be `\clearpage` or not depending on context.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\znewpage\oldsection}

\let\oldpart\part
\renewcommand\part{\clearpage\gdef\znewpage{\global\let\znewpage\clearpage}\oldpart}

\global\let\znewpage\clearpage

\begin{document}

\part{Part one}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Third section}
\lipsum[1]


\part{Part two}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this answer is fantastic. The only reason I don't like it is that I find it depressing. I realise I will never, ever think properly about TeX!

Comment: @cfr sorry..:-)

Comment: Woah, this answer is clever.  I had no clue you could define a macro to redefine itself!  Perfect for what I needed, thank you

Answer (score 3):

There is [an answer on LaTeX Community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=619) on pretty much the same question. For completeness of the answers on TeX.SX, I'm "plagiarizing" that answer here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newif\iffirstsection \firstsectiontrue
\let\@partOLD\@part
\renewcommand{\@part}[2][]{\clearpage\@partOLD[#1]{#2}\firstsectiontrue}
\let\@spartOLD\@spart
\renewcommand{\@spart}[1]{\clearpage\@spartOLD{#1}\firstsectiontrue}
\renewcommand{\section}{%
     \iffirstsection\firstsectionfalse\else\clearpage\fi%
     \@startsection {section}{1}%
      {\z@}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
      {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{\reset@font\Large\bfseries}}
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{Part one}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Third section}
\lipsum[1]

\part{Part two}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```